# how to keep products add to cart even i refresh the page use angular?

Tags: angular, shopping-cart

i tried to integrate the shopping cart in my project, i am able to add the products to the cart, and show them in the component cart, now i want even i refresh the page the products added to the cart it is necessary to remain, in my case it lost after the refresh.

**cart.service.ts**

```
  public cartItemList : any =[]
  public productList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  constructor() { }
  
  getProducts(){
    return this.productList.asObservable(); 
  }

  setProduct(product : any){
    this.cartItemList.push(...product);
    this.productList.next(product);
  }
  
  addtoCart(product : any){
    this.cartItemList.push(product);
    this.productList.next(this.cartItemList);
    this.getTotalPrice();
  } 

  getTotalPrice() : number{
    let grandTotal = 0;
    this.cartItemList.map((a:any)=>{
      grandTotal += a.total;
    })
    return grandTotal;
  }
```

**show-product.component.ts**

```
 addtocart(item: any){
    this.cartService.addtoCart(item); 
    this.router.navigate(['annonces/cart']);
  }
```

**cart.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.cartService.getProducts() 
    .subscribe(res=>{ 
      this.products = res;
      this.grandTotal = this.cartService.getTotalPrice(); 
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: You could save the cart data to LocalStorage on every update, and check for it in your constructor.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thx for u answer u can expalin more plz

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question so I've rolled it back. It seems that my hint set you on the right track, so you can post an answer to your own question here. If you have another question, post a new question.